# One iPhoto face is unavailable for syncing to my iPhone in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, photos.app

In iTunes, under "Photos", it's possible to check "Sync Photos from iPhoto" and then "Selected albums, Events, and Faces..." to sync only selected albums, events and faces. In the list of faces I can sync, there is one face missing from the list. The face is prominently visible in iPhoto, but unavailable in iTunes. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

The particular missing face has around 1300 photos in it, might that be relevant to the face's unavailability? How do I go about making this face (which is of my wife and the only one I'd like to sync to my iPhone) available and synced to my iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was simple enough. As written on [faces missing in itunes when syncing with iphone](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16013941#16013941):

1. Close iTunes if it's open.
2. Take one photo of *John Doe* and name it something else (whatever, as long as it's a new, unused name), say *Johnny*.
3. Drag and drop all photos from *John Doe* to *Johnny* and answer **Yes** to merge them.
4. Rename the face *Johnny* back to *John Doe* and quit iPhoto (properly, with ⌘Q) to save the changes to disk.
5. Open iTunes and check to synchronize *John Doe*.